# Is there a way to invoke an Action without sending a request?

Tags: scala, playframework, etl, devops

I have a Play2 app which serves some api.
I that same app, I added code that runs an etl based on Alpakka. Under the etl hood, there is a `Future[Done]` running that never ends. Currently I trigger the etl process with a web request at a separate route.
To deploy my etl service, I wanna be able to run my Play2 app with a special command that *ideally* does not open a server, but just runs that single Action of etl controller. If it's not achievable and sever has to be open, I'd like to trigger that etl process but isolate my etl box from incoming web connection. I feel that all of this is very hackish and probably there is a better way.

Comment: I think the best way would be to extract the code that runs the actual work and make your action just invoke it. Than build a separate application entrypoint (basically, `Main` class) that would implement command line interface.

Comment: But I rely on Play framework dependency injection to wire my etl together.

Comment: Play's default [DI engine is Guice](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaDependencyInjection), so you'd need to instantiate the DI container yourself (e.g. by looking into play's source codeand shamelessly copy-pasting :) ), but this is doable.

And you might want to revisit your design decisions :) Play is a web app framework, so if you want it to run "closed" to the web, you're probably misusing it. Specifically, "isolate my etl box from incoming web connections" is outside what Play can/should be doing - this is easier done at the network configuration or firewall level.

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up doing it is with [scheduled tasks](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScheduledTasks).

A task may be scheduled once and depending on a config variable:

```scala
class ProtonConnector @Inject()(
    config: TypeSafeConfig,
)(
    implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem
) {

  // Run the stream
  def listen: Future[Done] =
    itemsProtonSource.via(mapFlow).via(solrIndexFlow).runWith(Sink.ignore)

  // Schedule ETL execution
  if (config.scheduleProtonEtlTask) {
    actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(delay = 1.seconds) {
      logger.debug("Executing proton ETL task...")
      val _ = listen
    }
  }
}
```

Then we pick up `config.scheduleProtonEtlTask` from an [environment variable](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ConfigFile#Substitutions) (which has value set to `true` so the code block inside if would execute).
Then in our CI/CD pipeline we define a new deployment where this env variable would be supplied by task configuration. That deployment may be isolated from outer world too - that way, Play2 still spins up a server but it's inaccessible from outside of local network.